# Could not find assembly System.Security.Principal.Windows

Tags: c#, .net

In my solution I have .NET standard 2.0 project and it refers to System.Security.Principal.Windows package. All projects in solution have same outputPath (outputPath="../bin/Debug"). After building the application dll file form mentioned package doesn't exist in bin/debug. I saw other similar topics but I still have this problem. I have the problem only when I am building application on jenkins when using msbuild 2019.

Comment: I've noticed when when consuming .NET Standard class library, the packages that library references aren't pulled in to the consuming project. Did you try adding a reference to the missing package from the actual startup project?

Comment: guessing it isn't part of .net standard. you'll have to add https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Principal.Windows/

Comment: I added nuget package System.Security.Principal.Windows. My startup project is in .NET framework 4.6.1 but also tried add reference to the package